# Check if a function is $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$

Tags: schwartz-space

How can I check if a generic function is $ \mathscr S(\mathbb R) $ ? I mean the Schwartz space.

The definition asserts that $ f\in \mathscr S(\mathbb R) $ if:

1. $ f \in C^\infty (\mathbb R) $
2. $ \displaystyle\Vert f \Vert = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} | x^\alpha D^\beta f(x) |  $

Is there an easy way to check the assertion 2?

Comment: Which norm is $\|f\|$? For the Schwartz space I remember the definition $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)|=0$. (super-polynomial decrease at infinity) insteat your assertion 2.

Comment: I took it from my book. Anyway how do you prove that a function is S(R) using "your" definition? PS: I think should be an L1 norm

Comment: It depends on your function. The Schwartz space is known as a space of very fast decreasing functions. The best example is $f(x)=e^{-|x|^2}$. Each derivative of $f$ is of the form $p\cdot f$ where $p$ is a polynom, even for $x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)$. Since the exponential term dominates the polynom, it is decreasing to $0$ at infinity.

Comment: So everytime I have a function $C^{\infty} $ that is "faster" than a polynom (at the denominator) I can say that function is $ \mathscr S(R) $ ?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is arbitrary your function should decrease faster than each polynomial.

Comment: What the second part of your definition should say is that for every choice of non-negative integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$,
$$
 \|f\|_{\alpha,\beta} := \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \lvert x^\alpha D^\beta f(x) \rvert < +\infty.
$$

Comment: @MundronSchmidt and PeppeDAlterio The link in my post provide the proof of the equivalence between the definitions (as well as the proof that Schwartz functions are "rapidly decreasing functions").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Proposition.** Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. The following statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)|<\infty$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{N}^n$.
>
> (b) $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\|x\|^k|D^\beta f(x)|<\infty$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{N}^n$.
>
> (c) $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\infty}\|x\|^kD^\beta f(x)=0$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{N}^n$.
>
> (d) $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\infty} x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)=0$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{N}^n$.

*Proof:* see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1895426/70305).

So, to check the assertion 2 you can check any of the assertions (b), (c) or (d). As there are some alternatives dealing with limits instead of supremum, the work can become easier.